# Dreamwaver doesn't auto hint code when typing

Tags: dreamweaver

I'm using an install of Dreamweaver on my Macbook to code. When I type code on Dreamweaver the hint code still works but it is not perfect.  For example, when I type $ it shows the tooltip to hint the code but when I continue to type $_S it does not show code that starts with $_S. (I want it to show tooltip start with $_SESSION.)

Comment: Does dreamweaver work correctly on any other machine you have installed it on?

Comment: I think Kevin misread the question, the question is why `$_S` does not show `$_SESSION`. I'm not sure if it is the problem of getting `_` after `$`, the underline may not be read by the software. Anyway, I do recommend using other code editors, like sublime, it will definitely not having such issue at all.

Comment: @DesmondLai The question was edited after I answered.

Answer (score -1):

I almost feel that this is too obvious to be the answer, but... 'C' and 'S' are different letters.  If you wanted it to suggest `$_SESSION`, you should begin typing `$_S`, not `$_C`.